# how to alter story length of a feed

Tags: javascript

```
parseNewsRSS: function(feed) {
    var elm = '';
    var ts = '';
    var it = '';
    var className = 'hide';
    ts += '<table class="no-spacing list-items" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
    var feed_it = {};
    for (i = 0; i < feed.items.length; i++) {
        feed_it = News.parseGoogleNewsRSS(feed.items[i]);
        if (feed_it.image == null) {
            feed_it.image = 'src="s40-theme/images/blank.png"';
        }
        else {
            feed_it.image = feed_it.image[0].replace('src="', 'src="http:');
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            className = 'show';
        }
        else {
            className = 'hide';
        }
        item_date = new Date(feed.items[i].updated);

        // Main screen items
        elm += '<div id="newsFeedMainItem' + (i+1) + '" class="' + className + '">';
        elm += '<table id="newsFeedMain" class="main-screen-items" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>';
        elm += '<td onclick="mwl.setGroupNext(\'#newsFeedMainItems\', \'show\', \'hide\', \'prev\');" class="td-arrow"><</td>';
        elm += '<td onclick="mwl.hide(\'#city_date\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens\', \'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#newsfeed_items\', \'#newsFeedItem' + (i+1) + '\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.switchClass(\'#backToMainIcon\', \'hide\', \'inline\');"><img alt="News Image" ' + feed_it.image + ' /></td>';
        elm += '<td onclick="mwl.hide(\'#city_date\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens\', \'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#newsfeed_items\', \'#newsFeedItem' + (i+1) + '\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.switchClass(\'#backToMainIcon\', \'hide\', \'inline\');" class="main-short-text"><b>' + feed_it.title.trunc(News.getTitleSize('short'),true) + '</b><br />' + item_date.getMonthName()+' '+ item_date.getDate() +',' + item_date.getFullYear() + '</td>';
        elm += '<td onclick="mwl.setGroupNext(\'#newsFeedMainItems\', \'show\', \'hide\', \'next\');" class="td-arrow">></td>';
        elm += '</tr></table></div>';

        // Newsfeed screen
        ts += '<tr><td onclick="mwl.hide(\'#city_date\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens\', \'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#newsfeed_items\', \'#newsFeedItem' + (i+1) + '\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.switchClass(\'#backToMainIcon\', \'inline\', \'hide\');mwl.switchClass(\'#backToNewsIcon\', \'hide\', \'inline\');"><img alt="News Image" ' + feed_it.image + ' /></td>';
        ts += '<td onclick="mwl.hide(\'#city_date\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens\', \'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#newsfeed_items\', \'#newsFeedItem' + (i+1) + '\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.switchClass(\'#backToMainIcon\', \'inline\', \'hide\');mwl.switchClass(\'#backToNewsIcon\', \'hide\', \'inline\');" class="news-short-text"><b>' + feed_it.title.trunc(News.getTitleSize('long'),true) + '</b><br />' + item_date.getMonthName()+' '+ item_date.getDate() +',' + item_date.getFullYear() + '</td></tr>';

        // Newsfeed items
        it += '<div id="newsFeedItem' + (i+1) + '" class="ui-hide">';
        it += '<div class="navigation" onclick="mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens\', \'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupNext(\'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\', \'prev\');">&lt;</div>';
        it += '<div class="navigation" onclick="mwl.setGroupTarget(\'#screens\', \'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\');mwl.setGroupNext(\'#newsfeed_items\', \'ui-show\', \'ui-hide\', \'next\');">&gt;</div>';
        it += '<div class="item_container">';
        it += '<table><tr><td class="img_title"><img ' + feed_it.image + ' /></td>';
        it += '<td class="text_title">' + feed_it.title + '</td></tr></table>';
        it += feed_it.story;
        it += '<div class="more"><a href="' + feed_it.link + '">More</a></div>';
        it += '</div>';
        it += '</div>';

    }
    ts += '</table>';

    jQuery('#newsFeedMainItems').html(elm);
    jQuery('#newsfeed_screen').append(ts);
    jQuery('#newsfeed_items').append(it);
},
```

In the News feed items screen first it displays the Story title then it displays the description which goes like this
"The curtains have been drawn on yet another exciting Serie A season which, of course, makes way for months of transfer talk. Indeed, transfer rumors are something that can excite and turn off people in equal measure. Some of rumors out of the rumor ..." 
But i want to display the whole or full Story text with out "...." at the end of description.Need help Please

Comment: Don't want to sound too harsh here, but this is horrible code, I'd suggest you start from scratch and separate logic from markup. Plus you're using jQuery, why on earth would you code like that?

Comment: I'm aggree with @elclanrs. Also, I must add that your problem happens because when you are getting the RSS news, the content includes `...`. So, I think there is no solution if you can't get full news text